# how to send and get object using httpurlconnection?

Tags: android, object, post, serialization, httpurlconnection

how can I send an object of a class as post using `HttpUrlconnection` and again get it from sever ? what should i do to implementing `Serializable`? and is any way to send list of objects ?!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to call these:

```
conn.setDoOutput(true); // enable write.
conn.setDoInput(true); // enable read.
```

For sending data ( data must implement Serializable ) :

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
out.writeObject( data );
out.close();
```

For receiving data:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( conn.getInputStream() );
data = ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Comment: `doInput(true)` is the default.

Answer (score -1):

You can done this in 8 simple steps

### 1. Open build.gradle [PROJECT] and add these

```
allprojects
{
    repositories 
    {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

### 2. Open build.gradle [APP] and add these

```
dependencies 
{
        compile 'com.github.sangeethnandakumar:TestTube:v2.5.2' 
}
```

### 3. Now the class you wan't to send to some server via HTTP POST

```
public class Student
{
  @Serialisable("name");
  String name;

  @Serialisable("subject");
  String subject;

  @Serialisable("rollno");
  String rollno;
}
```

@Serialisable() is an anotation used by GSON library, Just use the same name inside it for what you name to identifiers like here. Ok you are done 30% now

### 4. Now initialise GSON & create objects of this class whereever you want

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Student s = new Student();

s.name="Sangeeth";
s.subject="Computer Science";
s.rollno="43";
```

### 5. Convert that object to a JSON text

```
String json = gson.toJson(s,Student.class);
```

### 6. Pack that JSON string to a DataRack

```
List<DataRack> racks=new ArrayList<DataRack>();
racks.add(new DataRack("my_upload",json));
```

### 7. Create a WebServer instance and setup a listner

```
WebServer server=new WebServer(getApplicationContext());

        server.setOnServerStatusListner(new WebServer.OnServerStatusListner() {
            @Override
            public void onServerResponded(String responce) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onServerRevoked() {

            }
        });
```

### 8. Just send that POST request

```
server.connectWithPOST(MainActivity.this,"http://yourwebsite/test.php",racks);
```

Everything documented here : https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/TestTube

Hope this solves